# NASM read file char by char

Tags: nasm

I am new to NASM and i have a project from school.
For start i need to know how to read char by char from .txt

after a long research this is my code:

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
;open the file
mov eax, 5      ;sys call open
mov ebx, file_name  ;file name  
mov ecx, 0      ;read only
mov edx, 0777       ; exe by all
int 0x80

mov [fd_in], eax 

;read
loop:   
mov eax, 3      ;sys call read
mov ebx, [fd_in]    ;file descriptor
mov ecx, buff       
mov edx, 1
int 0x80

cmp eax, 0      ;cmp EOF
je eof



;print  
mov eax, 4      ;sys call write
mov ebx, 1      ;std out
mov ecx, buff
mov edx, 1
int 0x80


jmp loop

eof:
mov eax, 1
int 0x80

section .data
file_name db 'hey.txt'


section .bss
fd_in resb 1
buff resb 1
```

but it only print endlessly to fist char in my .txt file.
BTW in the .txt file it says "Hey my name is blah".

i would love any help or suggestions.
thanks.

Comment: `fd_in` is a DWORD, but you only reserved one byte for it and overwrite it with a write to `buf`. Correct: `fd_in resd 1`.

Comment: Thank you very much it works. If you can, please explain why it was the problem ?

Comment: The first read fetches the first letter. The second read tries to get four bytes from fd_in (`mov ebx, [fd_in]`). But you had only reserved one byte for it (`fd_in resb 1`). Therefore, the second byte of `fd_in` is also the first byte of `buf`, and `fd_in` will become a crap value. The read syscall (`int 80h`) won't do anything but return with an error code (not null).  `buf` remains unchanged and contains the first letter. - the write syscall writes it and loops and loops and loops...

Comment: Again thank you very much for help and explanation !